# Replace with does not work even though I can find find two paragraph characters in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word Version 2105 as part of my Microsoft 365 enterprise bundle. I have a .docx file. In this .docx file, I have two paragraph characters below each other with double space that you get with a normal-style paragraph break in Word.

```
¶
¶
```

I can find the two paragraph characters using either `^p`; `^13` or `^013` (by ticking use wildcards), however whenever I try to replace it with anything, it does not work. I want to replace the both paragraph characters with a page break (`^m`). That does not work. I have also tried replacing them with simple text. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Please post online a small example document (Dropbox, OneDrive etc).

Comment: `find: ^p^p` and `replace: ^m` should work.  Per @harrymc you will need to give us an example of this before we can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The file was confidential, so I was not allowed to share it. I managed to find a solution. The trick was that the second paragraph sign was not recognized as such. One reason might have been that the document was automatically produced by wordcb in Stata.